# first sudo command on bootup, password shown visually said wrong but worked

Tags: boot, sudo

I tried searching for an answer for this, but the only questions I found asked were only for half of my situation.

I recently installed an appimage (openshot) on a xubuntu artful system and used firetools to run it from my home directory. I doubt this is related as its a trusted source, and not even sure it caused this, but figured I would include the most recent actions I took before it happened.

But basically the system booted fine, I opened something that I always open and have been for years, it prompted me for sudo pw, I entered it and the system said it was wrong, showed the full readout in plaintext of the password - yet still continued launching what i was trying to launch.

Comment: What is this "something" that you opened, and how did you "open" it? sudo should never echo the password back to you!

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hello Kusalanandam, thanks for the helpful reply - Its a VPN company specific application, I used it out of pure laziness a year or so ago when i was just learning unix things, didnt even know how to terminal really nevermind setting up ovpn profiles etc. Also I use a trezor as a hardware key and need to press the button for every sudo/drop to root. But like I said, I've had the same routine for a year never had this happen. and yes I cant believe it echoed the PW... makes no sense!